# list index out of range

Tags: python, error-handling, indexing

I am trying to write a program for connect 4 and this is the function that checks for a winner. When I run the function, I get the error message: list index out of range. How do I fix this?

```
def winner(board):
    # Check rows for winner
    for c in range(NUM_ROWS): #number of rows
        for r in range(NUM_COLS-3): #number of columns filled to win
            if (board[r][c] == board[r][c + 1] == board[r][c + 2] == board[r][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
                return true

    # Check columns for winner
    for c in range(NUM_COLS): #number of rows
        for r in range(NUM_ROWS-3): #number of columns filled to win 
            if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c] == board[r + 2][c] ==board[r + 3][c]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
                return true

    # Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner
    for c in range(NUM_COLS-3): #number of columns in a winning diagonal 
        for r in range(NUM_ROWS): #number of rows in a winning diagonal
            if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c + 1] == board[r + 2][c + 2] == board[r + 3][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
                return true


    # Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner
    for r in range(NUMC_COLS-3): #columns to make a diagonal
        for c in range(NUM_ROWS-3): #rows to make a diagonal
            if (board[r][c] == board[r - 1][c + 1] == board[r - 2][c + 2] == board[r - 3][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
                return true

    # No winner: return the empty string
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your rows and columns loop swapped:

```
for c in range(NUM_ROWS): #number of rows
    for r in range(NUM_COLS-3): #number of columns filled to win
        if (board[r][c] == board[r][c + 1] == board[r][c + 2] == board[r][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
```

Note that `c` (*columns*) ranges over `NUM_ROWS` there, and `r` (*rows*) ranges over `NUM_COLS`.

You do this again in the last nested loop:

```
for r in range(NUMC_COLS-3): #columns to make a diagonal
    for c in range(NUM_ROWS-3): #rows to make a diagonal
        if (board[r][c] == board[r - 1][c + 1] == board[r - 2][c + 2] == board[r - 3][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
```

But you also misspelled `NUMC_COLS` so your program never got this far.

In the 3rd block, you are also going out of bounds for the `r` values:

```
# Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner
for c in range(NUM_COLS-3): #number of columns in a winning diagonal 
    for r in range(NUM_ROWS): #number of rows in a winning diagonal
        if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c + 1] == board[r + 2][c + 2] == board[r + 3][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
            return true
```

Here `r + 1` will raise an `IndexError` when you reach the last iteration of the `for r in range(NUM_ROWS)` loop as you didn't limit that loop to `NUM_ROWS - 3`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused by what you mean. I put integers in instead of NUM_ROWS and NUM_COLS and got the same error message.

Comment: I spelled it out some more; why is the `c` (columns) counter ranging from 0 to `NUM_ROWS` (number of *rows*) and the `r` (rows) counter using `NUM_COLS` (number of *columns*)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this block:  (see how you're saying r+3...you can't go say, to NUM_ROWS + 3)

```
for c in range(NUM_COLS-3): #number of columns in a winning diagonal 
    for r in range(NUM_ROWS): #number of rows in a winning diagonal
        if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c + 1] == board[r + 2][c + 2] == board[r + 3][c + 3]) and (board[r][c] != " "):
            return true
```